# how to merge key array on array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

and i got a problem (its big for me) :(

**ok, i have some array like ...**

```
    Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/PO/5
            [total] => 65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/4
            [total] => 230
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/3
            [total] => 130
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/2
            [total] => 100
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/1
            [total] => 60
        )
)
```

***how to merge them if the array have same key value ... ?***

**the result that i need got is like this ...**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [detail] => Array 
            (
                [0] => Array 
                (
                    [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/PO/5
                    [total] => 65
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/4
                    [total] => 230
                )
                [2] => Array
                (
                    [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/3
                    [total] => 130
                )
            )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [detail] => Array 
            (
                [0] => Array 
                (
                    [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/2
                    [total] => 100
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [order_sn] => EU/2011/04/RS/1
                    [total] => 60
                )
            )
        )
)
```

im very need some help here, and im working on PHP ... what method should i do for this case?

i try too searching on google and in here ... but i dont know the keyword >.<

Many thanks before :)

regard, Stecy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach ($my_array as $v) {
  $id = $v['id'];
  $result[$id]['id'] = $id;
  $result[$id]['detail'][] = array(
    'order_sn' => $v['order_sn'],
    'total'    => $v['total'],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the array and build a resulting one:

```
// $a is your array
$r=array();
foreach($a as $v)
    $r[$v['id']][]=array('order_sn'=>$v['order_sn'], 'total'=>$v['total']);
echo'<pre>';
var_dump($r);
```

Since you do the paring by ID, it is wise to have it as the key and all the data associated with it as the value. There's no need to also have `id` and `detail`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($origianlArray as $key => $value){

 $newArray[$value['id']]['id'] = $value['id'];
 $newArray[$value['id']]['detail'][] = array('order_sn' => $value['order_sn'], 'total' => $value['total']);
}
```

Comment: Consider answering when you got something new and constructive to add.

Comment: @Khez  : At least try to give answer to some one's issue. That will be appreciated and also helpful to someone.

Comment: @Poonam I dislike fighting on SO, especially with people that don't know when they're wrong. Strongly urge you to look through answers before posting.

Comment: @Khez : I don't appreciate this. Since some one is giving his/her precious time to just help others. Every single post should be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: @PoonamBhatt : +1 for the last comment and correct answer also.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the PHP [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

Comment: Consider either commenting on the OP with such an answer or supplying actual working code.